# Proving a convolution inequality

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality, laplace-transform, convolution

If $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|dx$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g(x)|dx$ are bounded, show that

$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|(f\star g)(x)|dx \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|dx \cdot \int_{\mathbb{R}}|g(x)|dx $.

From the definition we have $(f\star g)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-\tau)g(\tau)\,d\tau$. I guess I need to do work on this right side, but I don't see how to simplify to get the desired inequality

Comment: Should the expression on the right-hand side be under a square root?

Comment: Hint: First, use the standard estimate for integrals and then Fubini.

Comment: No @angryavian .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the integral to the convolution:

$$\Bigr | \int_\mathbb{R} (f\star g) (x) dx \Bigr | = \Bigr |\int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} f(x-\tau)g(\tau)d\tau dx \Bigr | = \Bigr |\int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} f(x-\tau)g(\tau)dx d\tau \Bigr |$$ $$ \leq \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} |f(x-\tau)||g(\tau)| dx d\tau = \int_\mathbb{R} |f(x)|dx \cdot \int_\mathbb{R} |g(x)|dx $$

Comment: where does the last equality come from?
$\int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} |f(x-\tau)||g(\tau)| dx d\tau = \int_\mathbb{R} |f(x)|dx \cdot \int_\mathbb{R} |g(x)|dx $

Comment: @novo the integral of a shifted version of $|f|$ should have the same value as the unshifted version. So that first $dx$ integral evaluates to just $\int_\mathbb{R} |f(x)|dx$, which is now a constant that doesn't rely on the remaining variable, $\tau$, so it comes out of the integral.